# how do i make draggable circles around a fixed circle - d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

with reference from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanabel/b60sfx84/4/) i have changed the code as [this one.](https://jsfiddle.net/bharathappali/q7pL2xyd/) but i need some help to make the small circles to get dragged and reposition to their initial position with `d3.layout.force`

```
<svg width=500 height=500></svg>

var circleOX = originX + ((60) * Math.sin(0));
var circleOY = originY - ((60) * Math.cos(0));

var circle1 = svg.append("circle").attr({
    cx: circleOX - 10,
    cy: circleOY - 10,
    r: 10,
    opacity: 0,
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "blue"
});`

`var circle2 = svg.append("circle").attr({
    cx: circleOX - 10,
    cy: circleOY - 10,
    r: 20,
    opacity: 0,
    fill: "none",
    stroke: "blue"
});


circle1.transition().delay(1500).duration(500).style("opacity", 1);
circle2.transition().delay(1500).duration(500).style("opacity", 1);


var tween1 = function (d, i, a) {
    return d3.interpolateString("rotate(0, 200, 200)", "rotate(45, 200, 200)");
}
var tween2 = function (d, i, a) {
    return d3.interpolateString("rotate(0, 200, 200)", "rotate(10, 200, 200)");
}


circle1.transition().delay(2000).duration(500).attrTween("transform", tween1);
circle2.transition().delay(2000).duration(500).attrTween("transform", tween2);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Tried your code but the circles are very small. Dragging them seems possible but I would add a reset button to bring them back into initial position. And by the way your code is full of bugs. Make sure you read the API reference: https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md

Comment: Thank you so much [Vlad](http://stackoverflow.com/users/885838/vlad) . I'm a beginner in d3 trying to complete my assignment. Thank you so much again for helping with your code, I'll try that code.

Answer (score 0):

Not the answer but will help you get started:

```
`/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41136300/how-do-i-make-draggable-circles-around-a-fixed-circle-d3-js
 * @param {Object} d3
 */
window.DraggableCircles = window.DraggableCircles || (function(d3) {
    'use strict';

    var svg = d3.select('svg'),
        originX = 200,
        originY = 200,
        circleOX = originX + (60 * Math.sin(0)),
        circleOY = originY - (60 * Math.cos(0)),

        tween1 = function (d, i, a) {
            return d3.interpolateString("rotate(0, 200, 200)", "rotate(45, 200, 200)");
        },

        tween2 = function (d, i, a) {
            return d3.interpolateString("rotate(0, 200, 200)", "rotate(10, 200, 200)");
        },

        t1 = d3.transition().delay(1500).duration(500),
        t2 = d3.transition().delay(2000).duration(500);

    return {
        run: function () {
            svg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", circleOX - 10)
                .attr("cy", circleOY - 10)
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("opacity", 1)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .transition(t1)
                .attrTween("transform", tween1);

            svg.append("circle")
                .attr("cx", circleOX - 10)
                .attr("cy", circleOY - 10)
                .attr("r", 20)
                .attr("opacity", 1)
                .attr("fill", "none")
                .attr("stroke", "blue")
                .transition(t2)
                .attrTween("transform", tween2);
        }
    };

}(d3));

window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    'use strict';
    var DraggableCircles = window.DraggableCircles;

    DraggableCircles.run();
});
```

I will also assume you wanted to tween opacity, [interpolateString](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/master/README.md#interpolateString)
Well it is not supported with this functionality. Maybe there is other way to tween opacity. Not sure.